# PHP - Echo 'Array' error

Tags: php, arrays

sorry for being vague but I have a PHP script which extracts data from a database and displays it, however instead of outputting the contents of the database it outputs 'Array' the number of times their are results.

(Couldn't get the  to work again, script uploaded [here](http://pastebin.com/g6bZfjk3)), the script's output is also [here](http://jackcarlin.com/dayz/backend/qTop.php).)
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` is an array, in contains all record fields. Use

```
echo $rows['unique_id'];
```

instead.

And [don't use mysql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use `print_r($array);` or `var_dump($array);` to see

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `printr` or `var_dump`?

You need to specify the column or value in the array to `echo`.

```
echo $rows[unique_id];
```

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, `mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array. You probably want:

```
 echo $rows['unique_id'];
```